# How to match words with numbers only using regex?

Tags: python, regex

While I have simple regex: `[0-9]+` and test in on strings it sometimes matches partially or not matches.

For example:

> s = "19010116" - correct
>
> s = "19010116REF" - incorrect partial match

What boundaries should I add to not match this second case?

I try:

`(?<=\s)[0-9]+(?=\s)`

It works but when string is alone without other words in not working. It would probably work if this is allowed:

`(?<=\s|^)[0-9]+(?=\s|$)`

but a lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width.

My boundaries should be spaces only or string limits.

Comment: `(?<!\S)[0-9]+(?!\S)`

Comment: You could use explicit boundaries like `\b[0-9]+\b`